# Skrollr - parallax background in relative div stops rolling halfway up viewport

Tags: parallax, skrollr

I must have tried half a dozen tutorials and several days trying to figure out how to build a really simple parallax layout using skrollr.

I have 3 divs containing background images, each at different positions down the page. Each should have it's background scroll relative to it's position in the viewport, not on the page layout.

I can't of the life of me understand how to specify relative mode, and get my background image scrolling for the duration that it's visible in the viewport. They stop scrolling before they've finished rolling up the viewport.

My demo page here: http://3fishbeta.co.uk/build/040-skrollr/05-skrollr-positioning

The first image container on the page is :

```
<div class="imageContainer" data-bottom="background-position:50% -700px;" data-top-bottom="background-position:50% 0px;"  data-anchor-target="#trigger1" ></div>
```

I just don't understand the data-top or data-bottom settings. The image should continue to scroll, until it's container has left the viewport but it stops early.

In other words, the image stops moving when it's container's **top** reaches the top of the viewport... where it should be the container's **bottom** instead... I think.

Can anyone help??!

Comment: It might help if you added the relevant code to your question, together with some explanations of what you're trying to do in the code.

Comment: Sorry for the rambling... more explanation added.

Comment: I have answered my own question. The image container is 500px high. The data-top position needs to be ofset by 500px.

Like so:

data--500-top="background-position:50% 100%;"  
...where the top position is set to -500

I hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

I have answered my own question. The image container is 500px high. The data-top position needs to be ofset by 500px.

Like so:

```
data--500-top="background-position:50% 100%;"
```

...where the top position is set to -500

I hope that helps someone!